# trying to figure out how to make this function on()

Tags: jquery, infinite-scroll

The following is a countdown function, I cant' seem to figure out how to fit the on() function into it. The jquery documentation doesn't give an example that translate well with this countdown. Is it even possible?

Essentially I have an infinite amount of posts, and they're all loaded with infinite scroll one page at a time. The initial posts that load with the page all have working expiration dates, but the second, third, etc pages that load with infinite scroll don't have the expiration date. I'm assuming this is a case for on() but I could be wrong.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(function () {
    var date = new Date ('December 1, 2012 02:39:00' );
    jQuery('#countdown-timer-9968').countdown( { until: date, timezone: 0, compact: true, format: 'DHMS', description: '' } ); );
}

    );</script>
```

Comment: so you want the countdown to start on a click... right

Comment: Sorry (it's way late). So I have a bunch of posts with expiration dates, and I'm using infinite scroll. The posts on the first "page" that load when the site is loaded show the expiration date, but the posts on the second, third, etc pages don't show the expiration date.

Comment: I don't think `on()` is appropriate for this. It's used when you want to react to a user interface event in elements that are added dynamically. But the countdown timers are not initiated in response to an event, they're started when as soon as the new elements are added.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. Is there something else you'd suggest?

Comment: Check the documentation of the infinite scroll plugin you're using, and see if it lets you supply a callback when the new page is loaded. Then you can add the countdowns to the new elements.